# Azure AD Logout is not working - Angular SPA

Tags: angularjs, azure, adal

I am using Azure AD authentication for my angular based single page application. Sign in functionality works like a charm and facing issues with the logout. Once the user logged out from the session, its hang on the Azure AD sign out page and not get redirected to the URI given in the post_logout_redirect_uri and allowing users to login without entering credentials again.

Looked for the help over the web and spent almost a week to resolve the issue. But still I didn't  find any resolution for this. I came to know that already many users are facing the same issue and no solution provided for the same.

Has anybody faced this issue before and have a solution for the same?

Comment: Where do you logout from? the application , Azure portal or else?

Comment: Triggering the logout from the application and not from the Azure portal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could able to fix the issue by passing b2c signup/signin policy id in the logout url. Now its get redirected to the desired logout landing page without hanging on Azure AD sign out page.

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TENANT}/oauth2/v2.0/logout?p={B2C_SIGNUPIN_POLICY_ID}&post_logout_redirect_uri={APPLICATION_URL}
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you have added the app in Azure AD B2C .

Unfortunately,Azure new portal has removed **POST LOGOUT LINK URI** in company branding. In Azure classic portal , it also does not work for now.  If this is important to you ,you can upvote it in [this Feedback Forum](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/7207406-logout-redirect-stopped-working-for-oauth-endpoint).

Hope this helps!

Comment: I am using Azure new portal and configured Reply Url's and Logout Url while registering the app. If Azure portal does not support post logout then what should be the better approach to logout the session and clear all the cookies. Because even after logout the session it's allowing user to login into the application without asking any credentials.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. I believe that Azure Team will improve the experience  for this.